# Grouping GPS data into routes

Tags: gps

I've build an embedded GPS tracker which logs coordinates to a database, and I'd like to analyse this data and extract travelled routes and idle moments from it.

The way I think it should work:

Order the coordinates by UTC timestamp, find coordinates close together, and mark them as a 'route start'. Proximity could be found by simply comparing decimals, as I think GPS can be considered linear at a scale of ~3m. This brings up the trouble of selecting the 'center' of the idling: due to GPS inaccuracy, these decimals may drift around a little, potentially over the threshold to be grouped with the first.

```
10:15 to 15:12 - Idle
15:12 to 16:38 - [coordinates]
16:38 to 17:43 - Idle
etc.
```

How can I group coordinates in this fashion, and what complexities am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is work with some experimental data. Are you sure there isn't some distance D, where if someone moved more than D from their previous location it must be they are on the move?

Now, assuming that there isn't. Say that GPS precision is usually within a reasonable accuracy, say 10m, but sometimes you just get a point 100m away. What I would do is: as long as the user didn't move more than, say, 20m, calculate a centre for the "idle location" (just the average of the x and y values of all the coordinates). When the user moves beyond distance 20m from your centre, don't immediately assume they started moving. Instead, check the next (one or more) values; only if you see them several times in distance of more than 20m from the centre, infer they started moving.

I imagine this simple solution should be good enough for most applications, though it depends on what exactly the user is doing (how stable they are during idle time, how fast moving when they move), and the quality of the GPS data. I would start with something like that and see how it works. If it fails, I would analyse in what cases it fails and proceed from there.